# How can I get a value out of powershell system array object

Tags: powershell, piping, gpo

I have a following piped command that should print a GPO name and the group that is associated with it, repeating this untill all GPOs and groups have been printed. The output isn't right though. The name comes out correctly but the group says `Microsoft.GroupPolicy.GPTrustee` instead of the groups name. 
How should I access it to get the value?

Here is my piped command:

```
Get-GPO -All | ForEach-Object {$gpo = $_.DisplayName; Write-Output $_;} | Get-GPPermission -All | 
    Where-Object {$_.Permission -eq "GpoApply"} | 
    Select-Object @{Name="GpoName"; Expression={$gpo}},@{Name="Group"; Expression={$_.trustee}}
```

EDIT: The problem was solved, but I'll still copy the output of "Microsoft.GroupPolicy" -object here to clarify why I thought I'd be able to access it with $_.trustee variable.

It looked like this so $_.trustee.name didn't even cross my mind.

```
Trustee     : Domain Computers
TrusteeType : Group
Permission  : GpoApply
Inherited   : False
```

Comment: Your `ForEach-Object` call could be replaced by a simple `Select-Object`. Should speeden up your pipeline (as it doesn't wait for the prior statemtnt to complete). To your problem: What are properties of `GPTrustee` you could use as name?

Comment: To add to @Clijsters' comment: Try `$_.trustee.Name`. The fact that you're getting a full type name suggests that `.ToString()` is called on a `[Microsoft.GroupPolicy.GPTrustee]`(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.grouppolicy.gptrustee_properties(v=vs.85).aspx) instance as a whole, so you must specify the property of interest.

Comment: $_.trustee.name did it for me, thanks alot! I must have been confused by the fact that when I tried to access the Get-GPPermission object the contents looke like this "Trustee : Domain Computers" and thats why I thought the trustee was enough. 

Clijsters, I used the foreach because otherwise I wasn't able to pass the $_.DisplayName forward. Is there another way to access it at the final Select-Object clause? Thanks for your quick reply!